# Write-Error does not print to console before script exits

Tags: powershell

Say you have two scripts,

`outer.ps1`

```
function Main()
{
    Write-Host "starting outer"
    TryRun "outer" {
        & $PSScriptRoot\inner.ps1
    }
}

Main
```

and `inner.ps1`

```
function ThrowError()
{
    throw "Error"
}

function Main()
{
    Write-Host "starting inner"
    TryRun "inner" { 
        ThrowError 
    }
}

Main
```

where `TryRun` is defined same in both and defined as:

```
function TryRun([string] $name, [scriptblock] $action)
{
    try
    {
        $action.Invoke()
        Write-Host "'$name' successfully finished"

        Exit 0
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        $separator = New-Object string @("-", 120)
        Write-Error "'$name' failed`n$separator`n$($_.Exception.ToString())`n$separator"

        Exit 1
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when you execute `outer.ps1`, the output is:

```
starting outer
starting inner
<exception should have been printed here, but it was not>
'outer' successfully finished
```

However, starting `inner.ps1` directly proves, it's behaving as expected:

```
TryRun : 'inner' failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Error ---> 
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Error
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(F
unctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   ...
```

And what's more funny - if you change `Write-Error` to `Write-Host` and execute `outer.ps1` the exception **is** getting printed

I also tried flushing `Console.Out, etc` buffers before doing `Exit`, but that did not help

Now, why is it behaving like that? What is the reason PS is not outputting exception before exit? Debugging session shows it always gets into catch and executes that `Write-Error`

Comment: It seems PowerShell ignore error stream when you call script block with `Invoke()` method: `{Write-Error Test}.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are using .invoke() on a scriptblock. [.invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a collection of PSObjects. From what I understand, all data written into the output pipe is returned back to the caller; Eg: `{"a"}.invoke()` will return "a" , however, for some reason the contents of the error pipe is eaten or discarded (not sure why??).

You can fix your script by using the call operator `&`. So changing `$action.Invoke()` to `& $action` in `outer.ps1` should fix your problem.

**Note:** You should still be able to get error inside `.invoke()` using `$error` as in - `{write-error "a"}.invoke(); $error`